# AWK and arrays - more specific example

Tags: awk

My input data file looks like this

```
Town,Code1,Code2,Code3,Code4
Oxford,X532,X011,X989
Oxford,X532,X011
Hendon,X002,X011,X222,X769
```

I need the output to list the towns with associated code, like this

```
Oxford,X532,1,Prim
Oxford,X011,2,Secd
Oxford,X989,3,Secd
Oxford,X532,1,Prim
Oxford,X001,2,Secd
Hendon,X002,1,Prim
Hendon,X011,2,Secd
Hendon,X222,3,Secd
Hendon,X769,4,Secd
```

However, I also need it to sum up where the codes which appear in the same position so the above would look more like this

```
Oxford,X532,1,Prim,2
Oxford,X011,2,Secd,2
Oxford,X989,3,Secd,1
Oxford,X532,1,Prim,2
Oxford,X001,2,Secd,1
Hendon,X002,1,Prim,1
Hendon,X011,2,Secd,1
Hendon,X222,3,Secd,1
Hendon,X769,4,Secd,1
```

Currently the AWK I have written does most of what I want, but clearly, I need to create an array to store where the same codes are present in the same position for the count in the output - my AWK as it stands is

```
FS=","
OFS=","
}
{ 

site=$1
code[1]=$2
code[2]=$3
code[3]=$4
code[4]=$5

key=site

for (i=1; i<=4; ++i)    {
        cnt=i
        ++recs[i]
        posn=""
        if (cnt==1)     {posn="Prim"}
        else            {posn="Secd"}

        if (code[i] !="")       {print key,code[i], cnt, posn}
                        }

}
```

How can I finish this AWK, to produce the correct output? not sure if I need an END section etc.

Comment: I did some grammar and punctuation fixes. Can you edit question to make it make sense. e.g. ”However, I also need it to sum up where the codes which appear in the same position so the above would look more like this” — I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: there also seems to be a stray `}` in your code.

Comment: Why is the count (the last column) for `Oxford,X011` 2, but not for `Hendon,X011`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
awk -F ',' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { if (i==2) {print $1","$i","i-1",""Prim"}  else print $1","$i","i-1",""Secd"}}' file
Oxford,X532,1,Prim
Oxford,X011,2,Secd
Oxford,X989,3,Secd
Oxford,X532,1,Prim
Oxford,X001,2,Secd
Hendon,X002,1,Prim
Hendon,X011,2,Secd
Hendon,X222,3,Secd
Hendon,X769,4,Secd
```

To sum up where the codes which appear in the same position

```
ARRAY=(`awk -F ',' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { if (i==2) {print $1","$i","i-1",""Prim"}  else print $1","$i","i-1",""Secd"}}' file`)
for i in ${ARRAY[@]}
do
    PATTERN=`echo $i | awk -F ',' '{print $2}'`
    COUNT=`echo "${ARRAY[@]}"| tr ' ' '\n' | grep -c $PATTERN `
    echo "$i,$COUNT"
done

Oxford,X532,1,Prim,2
Oxford,X011,2,Secd,2
Oxford,X989,3,Secd,1
Oxford,X532,1,Prim,2
Oxford,X001,2,Secd,1
Hendon,X002,1,Prim,1
Hendon,X011,2,Secd,2
Hendon,X222,3,Secd,1
Hendon,X769,4,Secd,1
```

Comment: Hi,  sorry slight mistake in input file.  In essence I think my AWK as it stands is 90% there, I just need to add in an array part, within the AWK that outputs a count of each occurrence of the code keyed on site, where the code appears twice, the count would be two.  I didn't know if this array needed to be done in the main body or in the END section

Answer (score 0):

I'd process the input file twice: once to count the occurrences of town+code pairs, once to output the report:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    FNR == 1 {next}
    NR == FNR {
        for (i=2; i <= NF; i++)
            count[$1,$i]++
        next
    }
    {
        for (i=2; i <= NF; i++)
            print $1, \
                  $i, \
                  (i-1), \
                  (i == 2 ? "Prim" : "Secd"), \
                  count[$1,$i]
    }
' file file
```

```
Oxford,X532,1,Prim,2
Oxford,X011,2,Secd,2
Oxford,X989,3,Secd,1
Oxford,X532,1,Prim,2
Oxford,X011,2,Secd,2
Hendon,X002,1,Prim,1
Hendon,X011,2,Secd,1
Hendon,X222,3,Secd,1
Hendon,X769,4,Secd,1
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
BEGIN { 
    FS=","
    OFS=","
}
{
    site=$1
    code[1]=$2
    code[2]=$3
    code[3]=$4
    code[4]=$5    
    key=site

    for (i=1; i<=4; ++i)    {

        cnt=i
        ++recs[i]
        posn=""
        if (cnt==1)     {posn="Prim"}
        else            {posn="Secd"}

        if (code[i] !="")       { myarr[key","code[i]"," posn]++}
                        }
}
END{
    for (i in myarr) {print i","myarr[i]}
}
```

Results:

```
Hendon,X002,Prim,1
Hendon,X769,Secd,1
Oxford,X011,Secd,2
Hendon,X222,Secd,1
Oxford,X532,Prim,2
Hendon,X011,Secd,1
Oxford,X989,Secd,1
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.